# Unity | How Can I Rotate Multiple Objects In a Constant Matter Without Using Parent Objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, rotation

I'm attempting to rotate a tunnel, which is segmented into 6 panels, around a player object located in the center of the screen. I'm doing this by rotating each panel individually by the same amount. 3 of the panels work flawlessly; rotating exactly as I'd expect, while the other 3 rotate in a way that is completely different from what I want, and in a way that is difficult to explain. Notably the rotation of the objects that are broken mirror the function ones exactly (this can be seen in the inspector on the right-hand side, and I feel that if I were a smart enough programmer I would be able to figure out why but I just can't seem to be able to come to a solution.

Here is the code in question:

```
for (int n = 0; n < listOfPanels[i].Count; n++)
            {
                //input is a number ranging from -1 to 1
                float input = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
                var currentList = listOfPanels[i];

                var panel = currentList[n];

                float amountToRotate = speed * input * Time.deltaTime;
                panel.Rotate(0f, 0f, amountToRotate);
            }
```

Here is some media files that that demonstrate the problem (note the identical z rotation of the opposite panels in the Inspector):

[Here is a video via YouTube](https://youtu.be/vyoqcVHouUQ)

[Here is a video file via Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XhFgiFoFvcvzS_7vpOvfuspGWwOIQ7ky/view?usp=sharing)

[Here is a still Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eHic.png)

**What I've tried**:

I've tried reversing the direction the problem panels spin in, but that's a complete bust and I've also tried having the panels be children of a single parent AND having a parent for each; rotating the parent instead of the individual panels. This has not been a viable solution however, as I need the camera to be locked, and moving the parent moves around the panels in a very inconvenient way that would cause additional problems for me.

**Edit**: Creating a parent object for the panels to rotate around/with is *not* a viable solution. It's not a solution because the parent is rotating *with* the children. This means the panels location is not constant and the panels visibly move around when rotating in large intervals, which is very jarring.

I thought I came to a solution when I created a parent for each panel and rotated these parents instead, however this just mitigated the problem, making harder to notice. [Here is a video that demonstrates the problem](https://youtu.be/aa82rNaTyzs) and why it's not viable for me to simply rotate the parent objects.

Comment: Looks like the pivot (parent game object) of these objects is not aligned
with the rest of the objects

Comment: Objects rotate around their origin point (their local 0,0 coordinate). You need to set them up so their origin is at the center (now that zero points seems to be outwards and it needs to be towards the center). Alternatively you can do it with some additional math but in this case it would be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: why rotate them individually? You could place them under a parent object that is placed at the player position and just rotate that one around itself

Comment: @Nikaas This response was perfect. I was able to [set their pivot point](https://youtu.be/NsUJDqEY8tE) by giving each individual object their own parent located at the center of the tunnel and rotating each panels parent. This approach of having a parent for each object kept the tunnel location constant while rotating them exactly as I expected. Thank you very much, here is what my [current parent object setup looks like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UNvPNPEiqII3-PDnwntMQLvkyyCUq-vd/view?usp=sharing) right now.

Comment: @Nikaas Unfortunately, this solution was flawed, but so little so that I was just unable to notice without rotating it large amounts. The problem is that the position of the panels don't stay constant because they're rotating with the parent object (shown in post's edit). How can I use/find the additional math solution you mentioned because I, for the life of me, cannot find a viable solution.

Comment: Rotating around a point that is different to [0, 0] is done by: **1)** Translate the object so it's local-zero is moved to the point of rotation. **2)** Rotate the object **3)** Translate back to the local-zero.

Comment: @Nikaas Update 2: This was indeed the correct solution, I just needed to change the pivot point *without* using parents, which I thought you needed a parent object to change the child's pivot point in 3D, but I figured it out! I put an icon on each panel to see it's exact position in space and noticed the ones that were moving improperly had their pivot point off to the side. In the end, I was able to move all the pivot points to the center without changing my hierarchy whatsoever!

Comment: @Ripi2 I just noticed this comment! This is exactly what I figured out I needed to do, thank you for this perfect solution!